# Has Android any API to provide Date-time as input from user (startActivityForResult)?

Tags: android, api

I'm looking for API that provide Date-time info defined by user. I used in the past Contact List like:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    intent.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE);
    ((Activity) mContext).startActivityForResult(intent, LauncherUI.RESULT_GOT_CONTACT_INFO);
```

and on `onActivityResult` by using

```
Uri contactData = intent.getData();
    //Cursor cursor =  managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
    Cursor cursor =  cr.query(contactData, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
    String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
```

I could extract *name*, *phone* and *gmail*.

[image]

Now my aim to do the same for Date-time with format YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss. 
Something like:

[image]
[image]

I don't want to implement it by myself since this feature exists (only  in case if no API)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, Android has built-in date and time picker dialogs, see [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html) article for details (it uses fragments but you can use simply [DatePickerDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog.html) & [TimePickerDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TimePickerDialog.html)).

You can also use other open source libraries with a cool data picker:

- https://code.google.com/p/android-dateslider/
- https://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/
- https://code.google.com/p/scroll-picker-view-for-android/
- ...

(Use Android UI patterns app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.groidify.uipatterns&hl=es to find libraries like these)