# How can i get time and date from a user in android

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Has Android any API to provide Date-time as input from user (startActivityForResult)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12987008/has-android-any-api-to-provide-date-time-as-input-from-user-startactivityforres)

**How can i get time and date from a user in android to compare it later with system time ?**

Comment: Android has built-in controls for that, see [this question][1] for details.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12987008/has-android-any-api-to-provide-date-time-as-input-from-user-startactivityforres/12987081#12987081

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you want to get time and date from the user? Did you mean by allowing the user to pick a date and time or get user's date/time? Both are different. Depending on what you want to do, you can follow **Delicious Software's** answer or **Boe-Dev's** answer and also, please update your question to add more clarity.

Comment: In android two types we get the time and date 1.In android use CalendarView (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView.html), TIme (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.html), Date picker (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html).
2. or use **System.CurrentTImeMills();** this is return the timestamp output then u convert the date and time (http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis())
3. create in Date And Time picker dialog http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/D

Comment: let me be clear  , my app is to alarm or notify user about show time that he entered before , to alarm  him repeatably (the user set time first of a next show , then app keep going to compare between the current time and show time ,if (current Time==showTime && current day==showDay) then Alarm

Answer (score 0):

you just need to get the unix time from the device.

```
long l = (System.currentTimeMillis()/1000);
Data d = new Date(l);
d.toString();
```

this should help

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Date/Time picker views:

[Time Picker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.html)

[Date Picker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html)

[Picker Examples](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html)

Then compare with the system time as described by Boe.